# Invalid RGBA argument: nan

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, colors

I'm trying to display a scatter plot with 5 different colors: one for each '`district`'. Unfortunately I have this error showing up: `Invalid RGBA argument: nan`

My dataframe looks like this:

```
>         price    surface    district  
>     0    1850       46          1.0
>     1    1900       41          4.0
>     2    1925       55          4.0
>     3    1960       52          2.0
>     4    2025       57          3.0
>     5    2055       60         10.0    
     ...    ...       ...         ...
```

Here is what i did:

```
colors =['red', 'pink', 'limegreen', 'violet', 'cyan']

color_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(house['district']),colors))
```

thus the color dictionnary looks like this:

```
{1.0: 'red', 2.0: 'pink', 3.0: 'limegreen', 4.0: 'violet', 10.0: 'cyan'}
```

Then I created a variable col:

```
col = house['district'].map(color_dict)
```

Finally, i draw the plot:

```
df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'surface', y = 'price', c = col)
```

Can someone explain what's the problem here ?

Comment: If your dataframe has NaN values, why not just call `df.dropna()`?

Comment: Indeed, you must have NaN values somewhere. Based only on the data you've provided so far, I can't replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that there were Nan values somewhere in my dataframe even though I hadn't spot them.
As suggested by @coldspeed, I just needed to call df.dropna().

Shame on me ! ;)